# ASP.NET label is displaying "System.Data" message

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I am having a strange message displayed on the asp:label when trying to display data from a database. During page_load the asp:label is meant to be populated from a datasource however is displays the following message/text **"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"**

What could be causing this?

I have written a small method in the page load of the .aspx.cs page.
**labelName** is the one which is displaying this message:

```
public partial class edit_questionnaire : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OsqarSQL GetData;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string questionnaireId = Session["qID"].ToString();
            int qid = Convert.ToInt32(questionnaireId);
            GetData = new OsqarSQL();
            string name = GetData.GetQuestionnaireName(qid);
            labelName.Text = name;

        }
    }
```

Which calls the following method:

```
public string GetQuestionnaireName(int questionnaireId)
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("GetQuestionnaireName", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = questionnaireId;
            SqlDataReader qName = getData(myCommand);
            while (qName.Read())
            {
               returnValue = qName.ToString();
            }
            _productConn.Close();
            return returnValue;
        }
```

And uses this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [hgomez].[GetQuestionnaireName] 
    (
    @QUEST_ID int
    )   
AS
    /*SET NOCOUNT ON;*/
    SELECT QuestionnaireName FROM [Questionnaires] WHERE QuestionnaireID = @QUEST_ID
    RETURN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public string GetQuestionnaireName(int questionnaireId)
    {
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("GetQuestionnaireName", _productConn);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
        myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = questionnaireId;
        SqlDataReader qName = getData(myCommand);
        while (qName.Read())
        {
           returnValue = qName[0].ToString();
        }
        _productConn.Close();
        return returnValue;
    }
```

You were assigning the SqlDataReader to your returnValue rather than reading the value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `GetValue` method of `SqlDataReader`

```
SqlDataReader qName = getData(myCommand);
while (qName.Read())
{
   returnValue = qName.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is `SqlDataReader` type as string. To read a string out of `SqlDataReader` you will have to use `GetString` method. And as parameter you should pass the index of field. As you have only one field which you are trying to read pass zero here.

You should return value like this

```
returnValue = qName.GetString(0);
```

Alternatively you can do

```
returnValue = qName.GetString("QuestionnaireName");
//this is better to name fields
```

Or you can simply write

```
returnValue = qName[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line below - it is a data reader, not a string returned by the data reader:

```
returnValue = qName.ToString();
```

You should replace this with

```
returnValue = qName.GetString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are calling `SqlDataReader.ToString()`.  That will return the string of the type, which is in fact `"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"`.

Use `returnValue = qName.GetString(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You are converting `qName.ToString()`, you can try `qName[0].ToString();` with [0] being the index of select column inside your stored procedure.